# Replace infobar with post title in fancybox-3

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

Hello fancybox community,

I need help in replacing the infobar area of the gallery with the post title from my post.

So far, i have overwritten the infobar using "baseTpl:" leaving it empty to accept
the post title but it is not displaying the content passed to it using jquery.

Below is the code i am using:

```
$('[data-fancybox^="gallery"]').fancybox({
    beforeShow : function() {
    $('.fancybox-infobar').find('.gallery-open-title').html();
   },
});
```

The html to load the title from:

```
<div class="gallery-open-title d-none">
    <?php echo the_title() ?>
</div>
```

I will really appreciate every assistance in fixing it or recommendation
for a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Your code `$('.fancybox-infobar').find('.gallery-open-title').html();` would do nothing. Also, a live demo (Codepen/JSFIddle/etc) would help.

Comment: Thanks Janis, This is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/oshyne/pen/WNroNgE 
I hope that helps because the website runs on wordpress and it's still locally developed.